# how to perform one-to-one relational insertion in database

Tags: mysql, database, hibernate, one-to-one, insertion

I am using Mysql. And I have two tables which are one-to-one related with each other.

In other words, they both have a foreign key constraint referencing the primary key of the other table.

If I try to insert one record for each table, in which each record references the other. 
like:

The Mysql database will prevent such operation, because of the one-to-one foreign key constraint.

It is like the chicken-egg problem.

However, I noticed that in Java hibernate, such operation can be done in case two entity classes are one-to-one related.

How can that be done in Hibernate, because I notice that the two insertions(from Hibernate debug messages) are separated as I have done. So there is nothing special.

Or how can I force one record to be inserted even if the record it should referencing does not yet exist?

Comment: What's the reason for a circular foreign key constraint?  It may imply a bad design.

Comment: I think am also facing similar problem. Any solution for this issue, please post. TIA

Comment: This is a good question and had me wondering. sudmong's answer below is most likely how it's done with an ORM framework.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Put null value for one of the referenced columns, ref columns do allow null values.Later once you insert record in the referenced column, you can update the column.

Comment: Actually I noticed that hibernate did the same thing as you suggested, sudmong.

Answer (score 1):

You could try to disable the foreign key checks by running `SET foreign_key_checks = 0` immediately before your two insert querys and immediately after your querys, enable the foreign key checking by executing `SET foreign_key_checks = 1`.

More information about [foreign key constraints](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/innodb-foreign-key-constraints.html).

```
mysql > SET foreign_key_checks = 0;
mysql > INSERT INTO t1 (t2_id) VALUES (1);
mysql > INSERT INTO t2 (t1_id) VALUES (1);
mysql > SET foreign_key_checks = 1;
```

Comment: Disabling foreign key constraints is usually a very bad idea.  If you do do it, then at least put the whole lot in a transaction.

Comment: Of course you should run it inside a transaction. But i don't see any other way to achieve the required without disabling the foreign key checks ...

Comment: Sorry, ignore it. I am mistaking something